# Latent Heat and Ordinary Heat?

Tags: thermodynamics, terminology

We have a name for the thermal energy associated with the change of potential energy during a phase transition.  Unless I'm very mistaken, we call this latent heat.

Here we have $Q=mL$.

But what about the ordinary heat, the heat associated with a change in temperature?

Here we have $Q=mc\Delta T$.

Is it just called 'heat'?  'Kinetic heat'? 'Manifest heat'?

Is there currently a name for this if we wanted to call both types of thermal energy 'heat', then one would be 'latent heat' and the other would be .... what?

Comment: It is called sensible heat.

Comment: Thanks.  I knew there was a word, but without it, it was difficult to look up.

Although that seems to imply that latent heat is crazy heat.

Comment: @DavidElm You have to read *sensible*  as "something which may be observed by using senses", not as something "which makes sense". This way, *latent heat* means the heat which is hidden to the senses. Which makes sense :-)

Comment: Good point.  It still sounds a bit funny.  But I'll use it.